# How to end a python file after it writes a line to a json file

Tags: python, json

Long story short I am a desktop support turned programmer with the loss of our dev team. I am learning as I go (which has been fun but rough). I have a weather rack sensor that now puts a json response to a file with a single line, from there I can parse and post to our REST server with a python script. What I want to do is write another python script to run the linux command. Once the json is written to the json file, a linux command ends the process. How do I achieve this?

This is what I have right now:

```
import os

cmd = 'rtl_433 -F json -R 146 | tee -a testjson.json'

os.system(cmd)

#need to close after written to testjson.json


close()
```

Comment: Close what? Python isn't opening any files, and the script will exit automatically once it reaches the end.

Comment: When it runs the command, that command takes the rtl_433 output and puts it in the testjson.json file. I want to kill the command once it puts the output in the json file. That make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

You can also specify the programs return code like this:

```
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What's the point in this? Python will exit anyway at the end of the program. ``sys.exit()`` *won't* skip most things that the interpreter waits for before exiting.